# When are the ViewWillLayoutSubviews and ViewDidLayoutSubviews methods called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, ios6

When do the `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` and `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` methods of UIViewController get called?
What is the status of the view's frame before `willLayoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

From the [documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621437-viewwilllayoutsubviews)

> When a view's bounds change, the view adjusts the position of its subviews. Your view controller can override this method to make changes before the view lays out its subviews. The default implementation of this method does nothing.

`viewWillLayoutSubviews` gets called anytime your view controller's view has its bounds changed. This happens when the view is loaded, when a rotation event occurs, or when a child view controller has its size changed by its parent. (There are probably some other situations, too). If there is anything you need to update before that view lays itself out (and before your constraints are re-applied) you should do it here. you should generally *not* update constraints here, because updating constraints can cause another layout pass.

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called once all of your subviews have been laid out. If you need to fine-tune that layout by manually adjusting frames, for instance, this would be the place to do it.

View controller lifecycle can be a bit confusing, but it's worth trying to really understand if you're going to be doing much iOS development. [This article](https://medium.com/swlh/uiviewcontroller-lifecycle-behavior-8c023f433a87) is a really good overview.

Comment: you mentioned its not good to updated constraints here ?... I thought this is the best place to do that

Comment: Does this get called if we don't resize the child views, but we only move the x,y coordinates of the frame?  (i.e. bounds stays the same, but the frame has moved).

Comment: Article link is dead :(

Comment: Yea, That's annoying. I tried to track down another copy but without luck, if anyone finds one ping me and I'll update the answer

Comment: Article link is still not reachable.

Comment: I see viewWillLayoutSubviews called every time I update title text of my UIButton, which is subview of a subview, why? And how do I avoid it unnecessarily?

Comment: @cmyr I think I have found the article, let's remove the link entirely if this is not what you had originally.