# Change constraint when device is rotated

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using the following layout as a custom popup `UIView` in Xcode 13 (the white background is transparent):

[image]

When the screen orientation is changed to landscape mode, the constraint at the top and bottom are still 100pts. Because of that the middle part (yellow, `UIView` with `UIStackView` with `UITableView`,... inside) is really small and a warning shows up in console about the top (red) and bottom (blue) bar:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

I know what this warning means. To fix it I created the following function...

```
private let constraintPortrait:CGFloat = 100
private let constraintLandscape:CGFloat = 10

private func fixConstraints() {
    if (UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight) && UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        topConstraint.constant = constraintLandscape
        bottomConstraint.constant = constraintLandscape
    } else {
        topConstraint.constant = constraintPortrait
        bottomConstraint.constant = constraintPortrait
    }
}
```

... and call it both in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. This was working great but every now and then the warning still popped up, so I added prints to `viewDidLoad`,... and noticed that the warning is actually printed before my constraint fix is called. I renamend `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (`UIViewController` lifecycle [here](https://stevenpcurtis.medium.com/the-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle-b964cf18256b)) and Abracadabra!, the warning was gone.

People usually recommend to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` when you want to do stuff after the device was rotated but hardly ever mention `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and while searching for a reason for that I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27280562/2016165), saying not to use the latter to change constraints because it might cause another autolayout pass.

**Question:**

What should I use instead to prevent the conflicts (without changing the fixed constraints for portrait mode!)? Is there a way to change the top and bottom constraint automatically and solely in the Interface Builder, without using any code and only when actually necessary (-> always keep the 100pts in portrait mode, even with a long table, but switch to 10pts instantly in landscape mode when there isn't enough space)?

Comment: Are you certain why the errors are occurring? With the constraints that you have shown in the question I wouldn't expect a change in orientation to cause unsatisfiable constraints unless you have a fixed width/height constraint somewhere? (or something similar). Could you post the auto layout error into the question? Alternatively, this tool is really good for visualising the error https://www.wtfautolayout.com

Comment: Hmm... just looked again... Are you trying to centre the "pop up" view in the middle of the parent view? If so there is a less constraining way of doing this.

Comment: @Fogmeister I checked the warning again and the red and blue UIView (50pts) are definitely mentioned first. Afterwards it complains about the 100pts and then there's something about a fixed height of 320pts, which I'm not sure about where it's coming from (have to check again). I can't change the height of the red or blue view because I want the whole thing to look like a regular `UIAlertController`, so the next best thing is changing the 100pts constraints (which works but might not be the proper way to do it).

Comment: And yes, I want to center the popup in the middle of the parent view but also don't want it to get too big, that's why I'm using constraints (which work for both small and big devices) instead of a fixed height that could be too small for big devices and too big for small ones.

Comment: I think it would maybe make sense here to approach this the other way around and set a maximum height/width on the pop up view. So that it's size is defined internally, not externally. And then have it centered in the parent view. If you want to set a minimum spacing to the parent view edges (your 100point constraints) then still have them but set them as `>= 100` rather that `==100`. That would mean you wouldn't have to change them at all for different orientations.

Comment: @Fogmeister The space to the left and right edge should always be the same (40pt), no matter what the screen orientation or how big the device is, so setting a fixed width won't work for that (even if it's a max width) because auto-layout would simply take as much space as needed (if I understand auto-layout correctly). What does ">=" do here exactly? I never want the top/bottom to be bigger than 100 (ever), it should rather get smaller if needed after an orientation switch (and only then). I tested ">=" but got a lot of "missing constraint" warnings for the prototype cells.

Comment: I also just tested: `==100` with 999 priority and `>=10` with 1000 priority. This looks fine in portrait mode but with the landscape orientation it's using more than 10pts, which is enough to see a single table row but still isn't enough to make it look decent.

Comment: >=100 is "greater than or equal to 100" because I misunderstood your requirements. If it needs to be less than or equal to 100 then use the "less than or equal" constraint. I think it would help if you could add some more info to your question. Like what does the layout look like in different orientations and what's inside the red, yellow, and blue views. With constraints, the inside of a view matters as much as the outside.

Comment: With `<=100` the result is similar to the previous one: In landscape only a single row is visible and this time the the bottom constraint is much larger than the top one. That's another thing: I don't want it to be "less than or equal 100", only either 100 or 10 (depending on the orientation) but nothing in between. I've got 2 popups like that, one has the table with a lot more views and the other one is rather simple: `MainView` (white) -> `UIView` (has the constraints) -> `UIStackView` (contains the colored views). Yellow: `UIScrollView` with a `UIImageView`. Red and blue: Only a `UILabel`.

Comment: This layout doesn't change, no matter the orientation. I only want to change the top and bottom constraints, so the yellow content is visible properly in landscape mode on small devices.

Comment: If you are using Storyboard, use Adaptive layout (aka `Vary for traits`) - it will allow you to specify different set of constraints for vertical and horizontal view (see: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1343912-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-12-getting-started). If you are setting constraints programmatically, same idea, but listen for `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` to trigger the change

Comment: @KirilS. Isn't an adaptive layout overkill just for changing constraints? I don't want to change the overall layout, e.g. views aligned vertically in portrait mode and horizontally in landscape mode. I want to use the same layout (= 1 parent view) but with different values for the two constraints, depending on screen orientation. The original constraints are set in storyboard and currently I'm changing them through `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in code. I just read that `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` is used inside `AppDelegate.swift`, does that notify for every `UIViewController`?

Comment: Well, adaptive layout doesn't mean you make all views and constraints different. You only apply it to constraints that indeed differ in different layouts. For instance if you have (say) 10 constraints, and only 2 are different, than keep 8 universal, and create 2 constraints for vertical and 2 constraints for horizontal layout. They will be activated/deactivated automatically if using storyboard

Comment: You can subscribe for `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` notification in any UIViewController. As for `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewWillTransition`... that's the method often used in demos. But it causes many issues. For instance when `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called, the sizes of many components are not known (yet), so often you need to trigger `layoutIfNeeded()` several times, which is not ideal... Maybe if UI is simple enough, it will work.

Comment: @KirilS. Xcode's layout changed (again...): The "vary for traits" button is gone, instead you have to set it for every constraint: Tick `Use Trait Variation` in the file inspector, then use the `+` next to the `Constant` input field in the attributes inspector to add a new variation. [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/) says that iPhones always use the compact height in landscape mode but the width could be either regular or compact, depending on the model. So in the end I need 3 versions (default, R+C, C+C), right?

Comment: @KirilS. I have 2 VCs (both custom popups) that both need the same constraint change but don't want the other VCs to notify me about their orientation changes. If the size of most views isn't set yet when `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called, isn't that the perfect time to change constraints that have a fixed size then, so the views can use the new ones to set their own size, instead of the old ones that cause conflicts?

Comment: Like I said your luck with `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will very much depend on specifics of your code. You have to test to know if it's good enough. From my experience, it also creates the problem down the road, where the code is "working as of now", and any change in layout can cause some weird layout bugs. Other than those 2 concerns, it's NOT _wrong_ to use it.

Comment: The answer to your previous comment: most of the constraints are universal by definition. For example in your case, left and right constraints can be 40pt regardless of anything else, so you don't need to vary them. Top and bottom constraints are the ones based on traits, and one will be 100 with "hR Installed" checked in attributes inspector, the other one is 10 with "hC Installed" checked in attributes inspector. It's 2 variations. iPhone and iPad do not have CxC sizes anymore. I think you only need to worry about CxC if you support apple watch.

Comment: @KirilS. Sorry for the delay. You made a good point and after testing matt's solution it looks like `viewWillTransition` is better than `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. I do like the storyboard-only constraint solution too (feel free to post it as an answer), even though it's easier to forget about when you change stuff, so not sure yet what I'll use in the end.

Comment: @KirilS. Check out the `Device Size Classes` section in the link I posted, there are still a lot of devices that use CxC in landscape orientation. "... installed" doesn't exist in Xcode 13, you have to set both width and height of the constraint to either "Any", "Compact" or "Regular", otherwise it's the default "constant". In the end there are 2 versions: 1. default (100), 2. anyC + hC (10).

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillLayoutSubviews` is correct. Any layout changes you perform here, including changes of constraints, will be animated automatically in coordination with the rotation animation.

But how will you know that this call to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is due to rotation? Implement this method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition

Or, on an iPhone, this method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621511-willtransition

I like the former because it works on both iPad and iPhone. These are called before `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, so you can set an instance property to signal to yourself that the size is officially changing. You can work out what's happening by comparing the bounds size height to the bounds size width, and change the constraints accordingly.

Comment: Does `willTransition` also trigger for iPads? I just added it with a print and it seems to work fine but it's called even before `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is, so won't that have the same problem with re-draws? What's actually the difference between those two? I found `willTransition` multiple times while googling but people seem to use it to animate their `UIView` (e.g. make it roll in from the right), which I don't need or even want to do because that would draw additional attention to the yellow view not being big enough. I'm also not sure what to do with the collection or coordinator.

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified by accident. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The `viewWillTransition` doc says that it triggers whenever the VC's `UIView`'s size is changed, how do I know that that function triggered because of a rotation? I always check what the current rotation is (see code above), so I could simply remember the previous one, compare and act accordingly. If I did it that way, is there any reason to use `willTransition` over `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (or the other way around)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. A zillion things can trigger layout. Only something very dramatic such as rotation can trigger `viewWillTransition`.

Comment: I did some more testing with it and you're right, `willTransition` does trigger less often than `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and I've only noticed the print after changing rotation so far. Would you recommand comparing the rotation to the previous one with `willTransition`, just to be absolutely sure?

Comment: What's a rotation? It's an effective swapping of the view controller's view's bounds dimensions: width becomes height, height becomes width. Since `willTransition` tells you the new size, and the current size is still the old size, it's pretty clear when we're about to undergo 90-degree rotation and to which type of orientation.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. What I meant: Would you recommend comparing the old and new rotation you get with `UIDevice.current.orientation`, just to be on the safe side? Only comparing the size might not be enough for some people because you don't know if the device is held upright or upside down then. In my case it currently doesn't matter if the device is rotated left or right, as long as I know that it's in landscape/portrait mode but I'd rather keep the option open if I should need the exact info in the future.